# Android 2.2 image capturing issue

Tags: android, android-camera

im working on an app which captures an image from the cam, shows a quick preview and sends it to a server. now the problem is that i manage to start the camera and take a picture but the picture itself its not saved correctly (it looks like a repetition of the same image in smaller scale). This is done for an ZT180 device on Android 2.2. I want to say that the same application works fine on android 4.0.

this is the callback to display the camera preview:

```
    SurfaceHolder.Callback callback = new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            camera = Camera.open();
            camera.lock();
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                int width, int height) {
            Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.startPreview();
        }
    };
```

And this is the code for taking a picture (decoding to a bitmap and initially displaying on a Dialog window):

```
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(activity);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: i wanted to add that maybe its an hardware issue. when i set the PixelFormat to JPEG the camera does not start. it starts only with RGB_565 format. so maybe i have to transform the image from RGB_565 to JPEG before processing it